# ENTER key using in JTextField java

Tags: java, swing, key-events

I'm using two `JTextField` in Java Swing form. Now I enter the values in `JTextField1`. Next if I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> KEY means the cursor move to `JTextField2`. How to do this?

Answer (score 11):

Add an `ActionListener` to the first text field. In the `ActionEvent` you can get the source object, cast it to a `JTextField` and then invoke the `transferFocus()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `actionListener` for the `textField`.

Code snippet:

```
textField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        textField1.transferFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: -1, if you read the API the use of the requestFocus() method is  discouraged in favour of the of the requestFocusInWindow() method.

Comment: @camickr: why you had done -1 beside that my code is working.

The user is free to accept either the answer.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: "The code is running", this is not valid in all situations. Sometimes performance comes to the picture.

Comment: I gave the reason. The API suggests using a different method. Just because code works, does not mean it should be used.

Comment: I would still down vote the answer. First, the suggestion to use an ActionListener was given 20 minutes before your answer so there is no need for a duplicate answer. Secondly, referencing a class variable in the ActionListener is unnecessary. As I mentioneded in my answer you have access to the source object in the ActionEvent.

Comment: @camickr: I'm not actually getting what you wanna say! Please make me correct by explaining your line `As I mentioneded in my answer you have access to the source object in the ActionEvent`. I think you must edit your answer with an example.

Comment: Check out the API ActionEvent.getSource(). This method will return the Swing component that generated the ActionEvent, so you can reference this when transfering focus instead of using a class variable to keep track of the text field. This also allows you to reuse the class since you wrote generic code, not code specific to on text field.