# Capturing all inputs into JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Hi i used 4 JTextField in my swing form.i need to do is moving the focus from one JTextField to the other JTextField by hit the enter key and tab key.i done it successfully but the problem was the JTextField allows only numeric values if i give any value other than numeric value in the J Textfield the JTextField is locked and there is no focus transfer happen between the JTextFields.the code i was used .

```
package focus;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

    public class Main implements KeyListener{
        JTextField txt1 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField txt2 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField txt3 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField txt4 = new JTextField(20);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        public Main()
        {

         txt1.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener<JTextField>());
        txt2.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener<JTextField>());
        txt3.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener<JTextField>());
        txt4.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener<JTextField>());
         txt1.addKeyListener(this);
          txt2.addKeyListener(this);
           txt3.addKeyListener(this);
         txt4.addKeyListener(this);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.add(txt1);
        f.add(txt2);
         f.add(txt3);
          f.add(txt4);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);}

      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
          new Main();

      }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                    if (ke.getSource() == txt1)
      {
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
          txt2.requestFocusInWindow();
          txt2.selectAll();
        }
      }
      else if (ke.getSource() == txt2)

      {
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
          txt3.requestFocusInWindow();
          txt3.selectAll();
        }
      }
      else if (ke.getSource() == txt3)
      {
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
          txt4.requestFocusInWindow();
          txt4.selectAll();
              }
      }
    else if (ke.getSource() == txt4)
      {
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
          txt1.requestFocusInWindow();
          txt1.selectAll();
              }
      }

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    }
    class MyFocusListener <C extends JTextField> extends  FocusAdapter {
      //boolean showingDialog = false;
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
        final JTextComponent c = (JTextComponent) evt.getSource();
        String s = c.getText();
        c.requestFocus();
        c.selectAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
       c.setSelectionStart(i);
        c.setSelectionEnd(i);
           break;
       }
        }
      }

      public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
        final JTextComponent c = (JTextComponent) evt.getSource();
        String s = c.getText();

       if (evt.isTemporary()) {
         return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
           //System.out.println("must only contain digits");
            c.requestFocus();
            c.selectAll();
            break;
          }
      }
        }

    }
```

Comment: repeating @camickr in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585544/enter-key-using-in-jtextfield-java Do. Not. Use. KeyListener. Adding: do not use focusListener as well ;-)

Comment: -1 for not learning at all (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585544/enter-key-using-in-jtextfield-java)

Comment: @kleopatra: another question in the queue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591176/java-swing-program-for-hot-keys-for-ctrlx

Comment: @HarryJoy yeah, seen and down- and close-voted

Answer (score 2):

It was like that because you made it behave like that :)

**FIX :** In `focusLost`, replace the `if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))`

with

`if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i)))`

---

```
 public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
        final JTextComponent c = (JTextComponent) evt.getSource();
        String s = c.getText();

       if (evt.isTemporary()) {
         return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i))) {

            c.requestFocus();
            c.selectAll();
            break;
          }
      }
        }
```

or simply,

> remove the whole thing :) see the comments.

Comment: ehhh .. no ;-) The options to handle validation are a) InputVerifier if it should be done on focusLost, b) DocumentFilter if you don't want to allow invalid characters to be inserted at all ...

Comment: @kleopatra see it was edited in the same second you commented :D

Comment: yeah, see it - but still doing validation in a focusListener .. simply don't ;-)

Comment: Validations for Whatever Char_by_Char is job for DocumentListener, as answer for this question +1

Comment: @mKorbel you mean a DocumentFilter (vs. a DocumentListener), don't you :-)

Comment: @kleopatra FAQ says  _All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit and help us make it so!_ and you are bound to this I guess ;) :P

Answer (score 1):

1. No need to call `c.requestFoucs()` in `focusGained()`. Component already got the focus, that's why this method is called.
2. This is an assumption, but might be correct: "What you are doing is checking if textfield has all numeric characters in it and if not then call `c.requestFocus()` in `focusLost()` method. So once focus is lost from component(textField) and because contains non-numeric characters it again gains focus and you can't see any focus traversal."